# access dlookup multiple criteria Return Boolean And ordertype not equal to

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Function AllowPurge(FileID As String) As Boolean
Dim result As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

i = DLookup("COUNT(*)", "OrderMaster", "OrderStatus='S' AND FileID=" & FileID, "AND OrderType='E'")
If i > 0 Then
    result = False
Else
    result = True
End If

AllowPurge = result
End Function
```

OrderStatus is either marked as shipped or open 'S' or 'O'.

I need to:

- Allow purge - if every single order, other than E orders, are still open.
- Don't allow purge - if any order, other than an E order, is marked as shipped.

Comment: ***So which is is: vb.net, vba, excel, access, or outlook?***  That's 5 different answer's you'd require. Please [edit] your question and also see [ask] and also [mcve] as well as [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Use dCount instead dlookup.

Answer (score 0):

`DLookup` is for looking up an individual value.

`DCount` is for counting.

Try this one out:

```
Function AllowPurge(FileID As String) As Boolean

    AllowPurge = (0 = DCount("FileID", "OrderMaster", "OrderStatus='S' _
        AND FileID='" & FileID "' AND OrderType='E'"))

Exit Function
```

(assuming the table is called `OrderMaster`)

You were pretty close, except missing single quotes around the string, and missing a space, and had an extra comma.

The logic would have worked your way the same, this is just an alternate (shorter) form.

<sub><sub>*[Thanks Lee Mac!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660001/access-dlookup-multiple-criteria-return-boolean-and-ordertype-not-equal-to/49660871?noredirect=1#comment86331812_49660871)*</sub></sub>

Comment: Just a heads up: not sure if you meant to use `DLookup` or `DCount` in your code, but `DLookup` will return `Null` if no records are found, not 0.

Comment: @LeeMac Oops  thanks I knew that - that was a test (you passed)...  ..I've only used `DLookup` like a bazillion times, that's all.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your stated logic:

> I need to:
>
> - Allow purge - if every single order, other than E orders, are still open.
> - Don't allow purge - if any order, other than an E order, is marked as shipped.

I would suggest the following:

```
Function AllowPurge(FileID As String) As Boolean
    AllowPurge = IsNull(DLookup("FileID", "OrderMaster", "OrderStatus='S' AND FileID='" & FileID & "' AND OrderType<>'E'"))
End Function
```

Here, the function will only return `True` if **every** non-E-Order (`OrderType<>'E'`) is marked as Shipped (`OrderStatus='S'`).

Your current code seems to be testing for 'E-Orders' which have been shipped, and not checking whether every non-E-Order is open.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response

I tried this and seems to be working:

```
i = DLookup("COUNT(*)", "OrderMaster", "OrderType'E' AND OrderStatus='S' AND FileID=" & FileID)
```